# Command line multiple commands in for loop

Tags: for-loop, command-line, arguments

I need windows command line to find all files that end with .jpg.pdf and remove the .jpg part so it will be pure .pdf at the end, I have following line:

```
for /R %DIR% %%i in (*.jpg.pdf) do set without=%i:~0,-8% & rename %%i "%%without.pdf"
```

It should remove last 8 characters and then rename file with .pdf extension for some reason it creates without variable with this content '~0,-8without'

Any idea how to execute these two commands in one for loop? the '&' doesnt do the trick for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /R %DIR% %%i in (*.jpg.pdf) do ECHO rename "%%i" "%%~ni"
```

`%%~ni` is the name part only of the file, that is the part minus the drive,path and final extension.

Note that this line simply `ECHO`es the rename command. After verification, remove the `ECHO` keyword to actually perform the rename.